# How to connect iOS app to mySQL database using php

Tags: php, ios, mysql, swift

So this is the piece of code causing a problem. It gives me a fatal error and says that an optional value is giving nil.

How do i fix this? This only works when I enter the first field only (the name field) and then submit, it pops up on my database. However, when I fill in more than one field, it crashes.

#### My code:

```
@IBAction func registerButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

    let strURL: String = "http://www.blabla.com.eg/blabla.php?name=\(nameField.text!)&company=\(companyField.text!)&email=\(emailField.text!)&phonenumber=\(phoneNumberField.text!)"
    let dataURL: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: strURL)!)!
    let strResult: String = String(data: dataURL, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    print("\(strResult)")


    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: Use a breakpoint or print statements to see which value(s) is(are) nil.

Comment: I used a breakpoint and I know the problem is somewhere here, I just dont know how to fix it:


 let dataURL: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: strURL)!)!
    let strResult: String = String(data: dataURL, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    print("\(strResult)")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that one (or more) of your optionals is nil when you try to access it. Its important to understand optionals if you are doing swift development, I'd recommend going through the documentation.

```
let dataURL: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: strURL)!)!
let strResult: String = String(data: dataURL, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
```

In the code above, when you use `!` you are telling swift that you are 100% sure that optional contains a value. There might be an issue in either your construction of a url `NSURL(strUrl)!` or when calling the `NSData(...)` constructor and unwrapping its result with `!`.

Try something like this:

```
if let url = NSURL(string: strURL) {
   if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
       var strResult = String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
       print(strResult ?? "Something Went Wrong")
   }
   else { // get rid of this else when you find your issue
       print("Could not instantiate an NSData object out of that url")
   }
}
else {  // get rid of this else when you find your issue
   print("Your URL is nil!, check the strUrl")
}
```

Here, we first unwrap the NSURL as NSURL(string) constructor returns an optional (the string you pass might be an invalid URL). We then unwrap the NSData object and then coalesce the strResult when printing it (as its also an optional).

Comment: okay great, the data entered is being saved in the database now thanks to your code. However, the application crashes when I enter submit, theres an uncaught exception:   terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
Can you help with that or will you need to see more code?

Comment: I'll need to see more code, try to find out where the exception is being thrown from. Preferably in another question